# I made an AJAX call and jQuery won't add classes after the call anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've made an AJAX call that receives dynamic content and "lazyloads" it on the page. I want to apply a filter to the lazyloaded images received from the AJAX call, but somehow I can't add classes or the filter I want to the images

this is my current script for adding the filter:

```
function authenticFilter() {
    $("img").addClass("authenticFilter");
    $(".authenticFilter").css({"filter": "sepia(80%) grayscale(1) contrast(1) opacity(0.7)", "-webkit-filter": "sepia(80%) contrast(1) opacity(0.7)"});
  }
 authenticFilter();
```

This is the basic ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "php/database.php",
    data: {
      'offset': 0,
      'limit': $loadAmount
    },
    success: function(data){
      $('.articles').append(data);
      increaseArticles += 10;
    }
  });
```

I've tried serveral things including putting it outside the document ready function and using it out of the function, but it doesn't seem to work. The internet doesn't offer much help either, because only the click event outside ajax calls is popular apparently.

Comment: Call `authenticFilter()` from inside your Ajax callback?

Comment: Oh my god D: that worked. I look so stupid now. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that helped! I made it into an answer in case anyone else runs across the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to call `authenticFilter()` from within your ajax success callback:

```
success: function(data){
  $('.articles').append(data);
  authenticFilter();
  increaseArticles += 10;
}
```